# Imported backed up database and now frontend categories appear to be empty

Tags: indexing, magento-1.14

Steps to Reporoduce:

1. Flat products/categories enabled.
2. Products/Categories: Enabled and visible on frontend
3. DB Backup

   ```
   mysqldump --routines=true --single-transaction -h 'replica-db-fake-host.rds.amazon.com' -u'master' -p'password' --databases magento wordpress > 'production_backup.sql
   ```
4. DB Import

   ```
   mysql -h 'new-host' -u admin -p'password' -f < production_backup.sql
   ```
5. Update Magento URL
6. Reindex all: Tried once with `magerun index:reindex:all` and again with Magento's `shell/indexer.php`

At this point, the DB is restored and indexer has been executed, yet on the frontend, I cannot see my products. Instead, I see "THERE ARE NO PRODUCTS MATCHING THE SELECTION"

I see that flat tables exist have manually deleted them. When I run the indexer again, all of the tables are built and I see products within each of them. However, reindex_full.lock still exists though I never was thrown an index error.

Am I missing routines or triggers? How would I find them if so?

**Additionally** I have disabled flat categories/products, reindexed, and the products still do not appear.

Comment: When you view categories in the admin panel, are the products assigned? If they are, then your db probably imported fine and it could be an issue on the system/php level (any errors show up in the logs?).

Comment: The sys logs do not reference anything related to categories (confirmed that they are writable). Also, each category is populated correctly on the backend.